# .htaccess not working on my ubuntu lamp and xampp

Tags: .htaccess, xampp, lamp

help me about .htaccess.. this code is not working on my ubuntu lamp and xampp..

```
Options +MultiViews RewriteCond 
%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f RewriteCond 
%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

this code is working in windows xamp, but not working in Ubuntu.

Comment: You sure that spacing is correct?

Comment: Like I said, it works on windows and web hosting, but not in ubuntu localhost

Comment: The way it looks now, can't imagine it working anywhere.

Comment: here is my .htaccess
http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=0ZQzK0P7

Comment: What URL is not working for you and where is this htaccess located?

Comment: link without extension, ex index.php to index or home.php to home